# curl_multi_exec does not call remote function

Tags: php, curl

I have a Utility class that has to invoke a remote cPanel URL to create an email forwarding address, via cURL. This works perfectly well if I use regular curl_exec but fails if I try to make it non-blocking via curl_multi_exec - All I need to do is send a request and move on, I dont need to know the result - so it is a truly non-blocking requirement

Here is the code that **works**

```
$url = "https://mycpanel.com:2083/execute/Email/add_forwarder?domain=mydomain.com&email=email_fwd_146&fwdopt=pipe&pipefwd=php/piper.php&";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("user:pwd")));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
CakeLog::write('error', print_r($response, true));
curl_close($ch);
```

The response I get for above code is below (even though I really dont care about the response)

```
{
    "messages":null,
    "errors":null,
    "status":1,
    "metadata":{
        "transformed":1
        },
    "data":[
        {
            "email":"email_fwd_146@mydomain.com",
            "domain":"mydomain.com",
            "forward":"|/home/myconsole/php/piper.php"
        }]
}
```

Here is the code that **does not work**

```
$url = "https://mycpanel.com:2083/execute/Email/add_forwarder?domain=mydomain.com&email=email_fwd_146&fwdopt=pipe&pipefwd=php/piper.php&";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("user:pwd")));

$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);
curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
```

This call never seems to reach the server or even execute. Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not showing how you actually poll the curl multi handle for results.

Comment: I dont - what you see above is my entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)() needs to be called over and over again until the transfers are complete.

Comment: But that would mean that it will be a blocking operation - I thought the whole point of multi_exec was that it was non-blocking

Comment: No, it doesn't block.